# pgfplotstable: fixed zerofill prints some numbers in scientific format

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have a table with decimal numbers in the columns.
I want to show exactly two decimal places without scientific notation,
however when I added `fixed zerofill=true` it works for all values except very small ones for which it still starts to show the value in scientific notation.

Here's a short example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
value
12345.361
93.93
500
0.0864
0.1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibfile}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon]{data.csv}\data
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={value},
    columns/value/.style={
        column name={Value},
        column type=r,
        precision = 2,
        fixed zerofill=true,
        dec sep align
    },
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=\midrule
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    }
]{\data}


\end{document}
```

The example produces this output after `pdflatex` + `bibtex` + 2x `pfdlatex`:

[image: sample output]

How do I make `pgfplotstable` to only show `0.08` (or rounded value) here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the manual says,

> This key affects numbers drawn with `fixed` or `std` styles (the latter only if no scientific format is chosen).

In other words, you need to add both `fixed` and `fixed zerofill`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
value
12345.361
93.93
500
0.0864
0.1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon]{data.csv}\data
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={value},
    columns/value/.style={
        column name={Value},
        column type=r,
        precision = 2,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill=true,
        dec sep align
    },
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=\midrule
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    }
]{\data}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed this.